# Finding out the electric field intensity of an equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, notation

As I was practising some questions on electrostatics, I encountered a halt. I found this questions and was not able to solve it. Here is the question at hand,

[image]

What does the point $d$ mean? I do not understand that. Also, as P is outside the triangle, would the E field be zero or non-zero?

Comment: Just make the charges 1, -1, and 2. Charge 2 contributes only vertically, charges 1 and -1 contribute only horizontally (together). But how much?

Answer (score 1):

> What does the point 'd' mean?

A reasonable assumption is that point $d$ is the center of the equilateral triangle, equidistant from each of the three charges. Nothing else would make sense because the problem would be underdetermined.

By the way, the arrows at the ends of the dotted line between $P$ and $d$ indicate to me that $R$ is intended to be the distance between $P$ and $d$ and not the distance between $P$ and $Q_1$.

> Also, as P is outside the triangle, would the E field be zero or non-zero?

You seem to think that the triangle is some kind of physical object. There are just three point charges sitting in otherwise empty space. Their electric field extends throughout all space. The  total field at each point is simply the vector sum of the Coulomb field of each point charge.

However... The use of the letter $d$ and the fact that $R\gg a$ *may* be a clue that you are expected to do a quicker, approximate calculation using the monopole and *dipole* terms of the electrostatic multipole expansion, rather than doing an exact calculation using superposition.

Comment: I think I am starting to see the something but still not getting anywhere... Think I am an idiot.

Comment: Do you know how to write the field $\mathbf E_i$ at $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$ due to a point charge $Q_i$ at $\mathbf r_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$? If so, start by choosing an origin for a Cartesian coordinate system and figure out the coordinates of the four points.